# Google Auth token from Chrome Extension with PassportJS returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: express, google-chrome-extension, passport.js, google-authentication

I'm trying to set up a Chrome Extension that uses `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` to get the logged in user's auth token and then use that to authenticate with an Express server using Passport and the [`passport-google-token`](https://github.com/robertdimarco/passport-google-token) strategy.

`getAuthToken` is giving me the token but when it's sent to my server, I'm getting a `401 unauthorized` error.

I'm pretty new to Passport and to token based authorisation in general, so I'm not sure if I've made a mistake or misunderstood how it's meant to work.

My chrome extension does this:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive": true}, function(token){
  var url = "http://localhost:30000/auth/chrome";
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open("GET", url);
  x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
  x.send();
});
```

and the token is being correctly passed into my callback.

I set up my Express server and Passport strategy like this:

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as passport from "passport";
const GoogleTokenStrategy = require("passport-google-token").Strategy;

// set up Express and Passport...

passport.use(new GoogleTokenStrategy({
  clientID: --client id--,
  clientSecret: --client secret--
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  return done(null, profile);
}));

app.get('/auth/chrome', passport.authenticate("google-token"), (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

The client ID and secret come from the credentials I've set up at the Google API Manager:
[image: Google credentials]

If anyone can point me to what else I need to do or what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: where do you specified redirect url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two reasons this was failing for me.

The first, which I realised when I stepped through some of the `passport-google-token` code, is that it fails if `req.body` is undefined. I fixed that by adding the `body-parser` middleware.

The main problem though was the way I was sending the access token in the header. I had copied `x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);` from one of the [Google sample apps](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/identity/identity.js) but it actually needed to be sent as:

```
x.setRequestHeader('Access_token', token);
```

or in the query string as:

```
var url = "http://localhost:30000/auth/chrome?access_token=" + token;
```

Comment: Word of caution: Passing tokens via query params is insecure.